# how to make Nginx load staticfiles from a Django site

Tags: python, django, nginx, nginx-config

I deployed my django site with nginx, but my staticfiles such as css,js or media files are not being loaded, therefore I need help configurating it

[my site where the static files are not being loaded](https://jamelaumn.com/portfolio/)

In web console i'm getting this error:

```
16Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'deploystatic'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

my configuration in nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ecommerce.jamelaumn.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ecommerce.jamelaumn.com;
    ssl_certificate something/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key somethingblablabla/privkey.pem;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

my nginx.conf probably everything there is default configuration

Comment: Try to apply some changes: STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static'] to:
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]
and MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media' to: MEDIA_ROOT = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') ]. You must include 'import os' in the file. In nginx.conf you can add the absolute path to static folder, like: location / { path_to_your_project/static }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all run this command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and then update your nginx file like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ecommerce.jamelaumn.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ecommerce.jamelaumn.com;
    ssl_certificate something/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key somethingblablabla/privkey.pem;

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/your/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /path/to/your/mediafiles/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Make sure to replace `/path/to/your/staticfiles/` and `/path/to/your/mediafiles/` with the actual paths to your static files directory and media files directory, respectively.
To test if your nginx works properly:

```bash
sudo nginx -t
```

and if it is fine then restart the nginx to apply the changes:

```bash
sudo service nginx restart
```

hope it helps ...